# Apache 2.2 Reverse Proxy fails to load the images

Tags: apache, reverse-proxy

I am trying to setup a reverse proxy to my firewall through my internal webserver.

> WAN -> port 80 (rewrite to port 443) -> Internal Webserver -> Virtualhost -> Reverse proxy -> Firewall

This is my config:

```
ProxyRequest Off
ProxyPreserveHost Off

ProxyPass /firewall/ http://192.168.1.1/

<Location /firewall/>
ProxyPassReverse /
ProxyHTMLURLMap / /firewall/
</Location>
```

When I visit the site I still have images which are like this:

```
/themes/image.png
```

Which then points to https://subdomain.bla.com/themes/image.png

What I need is them to be:

```
/firewall/themes/image.png
```

Which then points to: https://subdomain.bla.com/firewall/themes/image.png

Comment: does anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: How do the urls to the images end up in the pages?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following:

```
 ProxyHTMLURLMap http://192.168.1.1  /firewall
```

below the ProxyPass directive.